# Implementation of a servlet that identifies requester and sends dynamic html for browser or just information for mobile/desktop app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jdo, multiplatform

I trying to think in a way that I can have the same methods to get and print data from a JDO database to all the 3 platforms, but with the difference that if it's a browser request it will prints in a dynamic web page generator. But I cant seem to think of a good method.

For example, if a browser asks for a post it will go to the code that prints a dynamic page + the info request. Like this

```
for (Texto e : results) 
        {
 print = "<table width='100%' border='2' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>"
                                    + "<tr><td colspan='2'>"
                                    + results.get(0).titulo
                                    + ";</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"
                                    + results.get(0).texto
```

But if one of the apps asks for a post it just returns:

```
 for (Texto e : results) 
        {
            resp.getWriter().println("Titulo:"
                + results.get(0).titulo);
            resp.getWriter().println("Nome:"
                + results.get(0).nome);
```

Because it doesn't need to print to a dynamic web page and gets the info from here. So i want it to return different content based on the user platform. But using the same method call.

Now I have different links to request the same info, one to the web and one to apps (desk and android). But I was thinking in having just one link for all the three. So far i though of

1º Get information in the login cookie about the platform that is doing the request and do a if in the print methods by two different types.

2º Or just send one more parameter always with that information and do a if... etc...

But I'm thinking this methods are really unsophisticated.

Anyone has any toughs about this?

Comment: Are you talking about returning different content based on the user making the request or different content based on the user's client (browser/android app/etc)?  Or both?

Comment: Just added the response in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's usually made by checking "extension" and/or requests's `Accept` header. For example for url like `/person/profile.html` you'll render this data as HTML, or if url is `/person/profile` + header `Accept: application/json` you'll render it as JSON.

You can use same data for both methods, but with different serialization type. It's easy to configure if you are using 'Spring Web', or similar, framework.